# SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay in - Sending email to a non-company address

Tags: php, smtp

Here is my code:

```
<?php
mail('myemail@gmail.com','Test','Test');
?>
```

When sending to a non-company address, I get the following error:

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\internal_tools\include\mail.php on line 2
```

When switching the email address to my work email, it works just fine. My PHP.ini looks fine, too:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
SMTP = PCMAIL1.mycompany.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = no-reply@mycompany.com
```

Even have the site set up in IIS7:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent [abuse for sending spam](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay), many email servers require that the client be authenticated as a legitimate user before relaying mail (forwarding it to the recipient's email server). You have specified credentials in IIS; however, PHP does not make use of them.

Here are your options:

- Instead of the `mail()` function, use one of the existing PHP mailer libraries that supports SMTP authentication (PEAR Mail, phpmailer, Swift Mailer, *etc.*).
- Install and configure [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) or one of the alternatives (here's [how to make msmtp work with PHP](http://www.jacmoe.dk/how-to-send-emails-with-msmtp-on-windows-or-linux-or-mac-os-x)). PHP will execute the program, which does support SMTP authentication, whenever it has to send a message if you set `sendmail_path` accordingly.
- Change the mail server's configuration to allow relaying mail from the web server's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your Smtp provider's policy. Or you need to check your Smtp server configuration (if this server deliver the emails directly)