# Cannot send email using Java code on Windows Server 2008 r2?

Tags: java, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed SMTP server and IIS Web server on windows 2008 r2 server. I am trying to send a test email using java code through localhost but i am unable to send an email i get the following error not sure what is that i am doing wrong. Apart from installing the SMTP server is there any setting i need to do because i just installed my smtp server and expecting that this code works?

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for marshell@gmail.com

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at LotusNotes.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:30)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for marshell@gmail.com at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1715)
```

**Java Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


  String to = "marshell@gmail.com";
      String from = "imrmsmtpmail";
      String host = "localhost";

      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
         message.setSubject("Subject Line!");
         message.setText("Test email!");
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }
      catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay in - Sending email to a non-company address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094813/smtp-server-response-550-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-in-sending-email-to-a-non-comp)  --- Different language, same issue.

Comment: Is your smtp server allowing emails to other domains?

Comment: Hi Jonathon, i tried my work email id but it still gives me the same error ?

Comment: Hi Askappy, i had relay restrictions enabled causing me not to send email other than the specified list and the list was empty. I just fixed it by adding to the list. Thank you very much

Comment: You can find a detailed solution at [**Resolving SMTP error 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for user@domain.com**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2005/10/11/412328.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to authenticate to send emails to this server.

AFAIK, you aren't providing any user or password in the connection to the server.

I use something like this:

```
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", true);
  properties.setProperty("mail.user", "PUT AN USERNAME HERE");
  properties.setProperty("mail.password", "PUT A PASSWORD HERE");
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
```

And to make sure you have all the parameters working properly before writing the program it is useful to make a telnet to the mail port (25) to make sure you can send an email directly writing the codes into the server.

In the following link you have an example:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119/en

Altough it may sound extremely technical, it worth to try to make sure that the server send emails from your machine with the given parameters: username (or not username at all), destination address, etc.